# Use Laravel's migration to manage db schema from a single config file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration, database-schema

I want to use Laravel's migration to manage my database. But I ***need*** to have a single configuration file where I store the schema. Something like this :

```
        {
           user: {
                    "id":"increments",
                    "name":"string",
                    "timestamps":"timestamps()"
                 }
        }
```

And when I change this file again to the text below

```
        {
           user: {
                    "id":"increments",
                    "name":"string",
                    "password":"string",
                    "timestamps":"timestamps()"
                 }
        }
```

I want to be able to run a command and have the database be changed without losing any data or creating an additional config file.

Can I achieve this using laravel migrations or if you know of any other solution that can help me and I would be able to use that on laravel without losing any of laravel's database management tools, please comment. 
Thank you.

Comment: This isn't how migrations work, unfortunately. They are completely linear, and previous migrations will never know about future migrations. This also prevents the migration system from tracking changes (alters, etc), therefore going against the migration design paradigm.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yes I know. That's why I'm saying that I might need to use Phinx or some better solution for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan make:migration add_password_to_user` ( are you sure the table is called user and not users? )

In your new migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('user', function($table) {
        $table->string('password');
    });
}
```

Don't forget the rollback

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('user', function($table) {
        $table->dropColumn('password');
    });
}
```

The table should be **users** if you have the model **User** .. otherwise make sure to have `protected $table = 'user';` on the model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations

The --table and --create options may also be used to indicate the name of the table and whether the migration will be creating a new table. These options simply pre-fill the generated migration stub file with the specified table:

php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users

php artisan make:migration add_votes_to_users_table --table=users

Comment: Thanks but I don't think you understood my question :)

Comment: This does not answer the question.